# Networkx - entropy of subgraphs generated from detected communities

Tags: python, networkx, entropy, complex-networks

I have 4 functions for some statistical calculations in complex networks analysis.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import math
from astropy.io import fits
```

Degree distribution of graph:

```
def degree_distribution(G):
    vk = dict(G.degree())
    vk = list(vk.values()) # we get only the degree values
    maxk = np.max(vk)
    mink = np.min(min)
    kvalues= np.arange(0,maxk+1) # possible values of k
    Pk = np.zeros(maxk+1) # P(k)
    for k in vk:
        Pk[k] = Pk[k] + 1
    Pk = Pk/sum(Pk) # the sum of the elements of P(k) must to be equal to one
    
    return kvalues,Pk
```

Community detection of graph:

```
def calculate_community_modularity(graph):
    
    communities = greedy_modularity_communities(graph) # algorithm
    modularity_dict = {} # Create a blank dictionary

    for i,c in enumerate(communities): # Loop through the list of communities, keeping track of the number for the community
        for name in c: # Loop through each neuron in a community
            modularity_dict[name] = i # Create an entry in the dictionary for the neuron, where the value is which group they belong to.

    nx.set_node_attributes(graph, modularity_dict, 'modularity')
    
    print (graph_name)
    for i,c in enumerate(communities): # Loop through the list of communities
        #if len(c) > 2: # Filter out modularity classes with 2 or fewer nodes
            print('Class '+str(i)+':', len(c)) # Print out the classes and their member numbers
    return modularity_dict
```

Modularity score of graph:

```
def modularity_score(graph):
    return nx_comm.modularity(graph, nx_comm.label_propagation_communities(graph))
```

and finally graph Entropy:

```
def shannon_entropy(G):
    k,Pk = degree_distribution(G)
    H = 0
    for p in Pk:
        if(p > 0):
            H = H - p*math.log(p, 2)
    return H
```

### Question

What I would like to achieve now is find local entropy for each community (turned into a subgraph), with preserved edges information.

Is this possible? How so?

### Edit

Matrix being used is in this link:

[dataset](https://cosmosimfrazza.myfreesites.net/cosmic-web-and-brain-network-datasets)

```
with fits.open('mind_dataset/matrix_CEREBELLUM_large.fits') as data:
    matrix = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
```

and then turn the adjacency matrix into a graph, 'graph', or 'G' like so:

```
def matrix_to_graph(matrix):
    from_matrix = matrix.copy()
    to_numpy = from_matrix.to_numpy()
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(to_numpy)
    return G
```

### Edit 2

Based on the proposed answer below I have created another function:

```
def community_entropy(modularity_dict):
    communities = {}

    #create communities as lists of nodes
    for node, community in modularity_dict.items():
        if community not in communities.keys():
            communities[community] = [node]
        else:
            communities[community].append(node)

    print(communities)
    #transform lists of nodes to actual subgraphs
    for subgraph, community in communities.items():
        communities[community] = nx.Graph.subgraph(subgraph)
        
    local_entropy = {}
    for subgraph, community in communities.items():
        local_entropy[community] = shannon_entropy(subgraph)
        
    return local_entropy
```

and:

```
cerebellum_graph = matrix_to_graph(matrix)
modularity_dict_cereb = calculate_community_modularity(cerebellum_graph)
community_entropy_cereb = community_entropy(modularity_dict_cereb)
```

But it throws the error:

> TypeError: subgraph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nodes'

Comment: it looks like, in `calculate_community_modularity`,  you use `greedy_modularity_communities` to create a dict, `modularity_dict`, which maps a node in your graph to a community. Why cant you take each subgraph community in `modularity_dict` and pass it into `shannon_entropy` to calculate the entropy for that community?

Comment: if you'd like to answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: Can you define what your inputs to each function are? for instance, what is `G` and what is `graph`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the code I provided as an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901680/networkx-create-graphs-from-communities/70907819#70907819) to create graphs from communities. You can first create different graphs for each of your communities (based on the *community* edge attribute of your graph). You can then compute the entropy for each community with your `shannon_entropy` and `degree_distribution` function.

See code below based on the karate club example you provided in your other question referenced above:

```py
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.community as nx_comm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def degree_distribution(G):
    vk = dict(G.degree())
    vk = list(vk.values()) # we get only the degree values
    maxk = np.max(vk)
    mink = np.min(min)
    kvalues= np.arange(0,maxk+1) # possible values of k
    Pk = np.zeros(maxk+1) # P(k)
    for k in vk:
        Pk[k] = Pk[k] + 1
    Pk = Pk/sum(Pk) # the sum of the elements of P(k) must to be equal to one
    
    return kvalues,Pk

def shannon_entropy(G):
    k,Pk = degree_distribution(G)
    H = 0
    for p in Pk:
        if(p > 0):
            H = H - p*math.log(p, 2)
    return H


G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# Find the communities
communities = sorted(nx_comm.greedy_modularity_communities(G), key=len, reverse=True)

# Count the communities
print(f"The club has {len(communities)} communities.")

'''Add community to node attributes'''
for c, v_c in enumerate(communities):
    for v in v_c:
        # Add 1 to save 0 for external edges
        G.nodes[v]['community'] = c + 1

'''Find internal edges and add their community to their attributes'''
for v, w, in G.edges:
    if G.nodes[v]['community'] == G.nodes[w]['community']:
        # Internal edge, mark with community
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = G.nodes[v]['community']
    else:
        # External edge, mark as 0
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = 0


N_coms=len(communities)
edges_coms=[]#edge list for each community
coms_G=[nx.Graph() for _ in range(N_coms)] #community graphs
colors=['tab:blue','tab:orange','tab:green']
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

for i in range(N_coms):
  edges_coms.append([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True) if d['community'] == i+1])#identify edges of interest using the edge attribute
  coms_G[i].add_edges_from(edges_coms[i]) #add edges

ent_coms=[shannon_entropy(coms_G[i]) for i in range(N_coms)] #Compute entropy
for i in range(N_coms):
  plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)#plot communities
  plt.title('Community '+str(i+1)+ ', entropy: '+str(np.round(ent_coms[i],1)))
  pos=nx.circular_layout(coms_G[i])
  nx.draw(coms_G[i],pos=pos,with_labels=True,node_color=colors[i])
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in `calculate_community_modularity`, you use `greedy_modularity_communities` to create a dict, `modularity_dict`, which maps a node in your graph to a `community`. If I understand correctly, you can take each subgraph community in `modularity_dict` and pass it into `shannon_entropy` to calculate the entropy for that community.

---

## pseudo code

this is pseudo code, so there may be some errors. This should convey the principle, though.

after running `calculate_community_modularity`, you have a
dict like this, where the key is each node, and the value is that which the community belongs to

```
modularity_dict = {node_1: community_1, node_2: community_1, node_3: community_2}
```

I've never used `nx`, but it looks like you can [extract a subgraph based on a list of nodes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html). So you would iterate through your dict, and create a list of nodes for each community. then you would use that list of nodes to extract the actual `nx` subgraph for that community.

```
communities = {}

#create communities as lists of nodes
for node, community in modularity_dict.iteritems():
    if community not in communities.keys():
        communities[community] = [node]
    else:
        communities[community].append(node)

#transform lists of nodes to actual subgraphs
for subgraph, community in communities.iteritems():
    communities[community] = networkx.Graph.subgraph(subgraph)
```

now that `communities` is a dict with key of the community id, and a value of the `nx` subgraph which defines that community, you should be able to run those subgraphs through `shannon_entropy`, as the type of the subgraphs is the same as the type of your original graph

```
local_entropy = {}
for subgraph, community in communities.iteritems():
    local_entropy[community] = shannon_entropy(subgraph)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I meant an answer with the code…

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll add some pseudo code describing what I'm thinking

Comment: I have edit the question with the real matrix, and how to turn it into a graph.

Comment: in order to get the real matrix, you'll need the import  `from astropy.io import fits`. but you can use pseudo code if you prefer

Comment: thank you but somehow this does not work, throwing the error: `TypeError: subgraph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nodes'`. furthermore, I think a graph object needs information about edges as well: `Graph with 1858 nodes and 8570 edges` and this seems to be missing in communities

Comment: the only input to `subgraph` appears to be `nodes`. Are you not putting anything as the input to `subgraph()`?

Comment: maybe it's better to not use pseudo code, band rather the real matrix in the link, because I have the matrix, and the means to transform it into graphs and so on...